# Getting Attributes in LINQToXML

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML

```
<sss>
  <session status="true" reason="Any reason" />
  <employee name="abc" address="abc 123" isManager="false"/>
</sss>
```

I'm trying to access the value of the reason attribute by using the following LINQ Query:

```
 Dim results1 = (From r In document.Root.Elements("session").ToList()
                Select r).First()

results1.Attributes("reason")(0).Value
```

Though I am able to access the value of the attribute by using the above syntax, but I am a bit confused as why I have to use (0) in front of reason (like an array) as the result is a single attribute.

Any alternate option to access the value or do a loop in case of multiple rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your `XDocument`

```
Dim document = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
               <sss>
                  <session status="true" reason="Any reason" />
                  <employee name="abc" address="abc 123" isManager="false"/>
               </sss>
```

you could simply use XML literals; no need for LINQ:

```
Dim reason = document.Root.<session>.@reason
```

`reason` is now a `String` with the value `Any reason`

---

To answer your other question:

You're using the [`Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341024(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which returns a collection of attributes. If you want to get a single element, use the [`Attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the attribute of first "session" element, then it can be obtained as below:

```
Dim results1 = document.Descendants("session").First().Attribute("reason").Value
```